# Looking for the correct part to extend a portable dishwasher drain hose

Tags: dishwasher, hose, extension

I have a Danby Portable dishwasher ddw1899wp. Turns out I can't build it in permanently, so I want to extend the drain hoses so I don't have to wheel it around the corner of the counter and back every time.

These are the hoses: https://www.appliancepartspros.com/danby-drain-hose-12676000000951-ap6040067.html

I think it's a pretty standard PVC 3/4 inch hose. I haven't been able to find some kind of 2 ended male 3/4-3/4 connector, which was my first thought.

What would be the best way to add an extension to each hose?

[image]

Comment: That doesn't look like garden hose connector to me.  My rec would be to take the hose to a plumbing store (might get lucky at HD or Lowe's) and see what size/type the fittings really are.

Answer (score 3):

Male-to-male adapters may not be racked with the garden hoses; in my store there's a set of drawers at the back of the plumbing section which holds all the less common adapters between sizes and threads.

The plumbing section may also have short lengths of pipe (metal or plastic) with hose thread on both ends, or completely threaded. That's been my usual solution for this particular task. Make sure that it's hose thread, not pipe thread, by trying to attach a hose to it before you buy it; I've gotten that wrong a few times.